# Tag revision value shown on Gerrit is different from the commit the tag points to

Tags: git, tags, gerrit, revision

On the Gerrit page, I see the Revision name/value of a tag to be below:

```
Tag Name        Revision  
r2.5.7_01232019 469043b4b5675d7c4a518d3cf94bf10ff8d084c4 (gitweb)
```

But when I do `git show r2.5.7_01232019`, it tells me that the commit hash 
the tag points to is

```
commit 1f8f364e317c6ead8a81eeee76f3deec2d9eda4a
```

Why is the Tag revision no the same as the commit it points to?

Comment: Is the tag an annotated tag?

Answer (score 0):

On the Gerrit page you see remote git tags. With `git show` you see your local git tags.
It can be that they are not in sync.
For example, you created a tag and pushed it to remote. After that someone else could push a tag with the same name with `git push --force` and your initial tag was updated on the remote.